# How can I access a button in a Listview thats wrapped in a Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, controls

I have a Button (Id="checkInBtn") inside of a ListView's ItemTemplate, and that ListView is in an UpdatePanel. Therefore, I am not able to access the Button by its ID in my codebehind (I've only been able to access it so far by its eventHandler and casting it as sender [as solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856217/cant-access-button-in-codebehind/57856316?noredirect=1#comment102142311_57856316) - so only been able to access it when it is clicked on)

Now, I'd like to access this Button from a seperate method - what I need to do is have this Button "blink" after a certain condition is met.
Is there any other way to go about accessing this Button Control ?

ASPX:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateList" runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="refreshInstructorList" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Timer ID="refreshInstructorList" runat="server" Interval="180000" OnTick="RefreshList"></asp:Timer> <!-- Every 3 minutes/ 180k ms -->

                    <asp:ListView
                    ID="lvInstructors"
                     runat="server"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     ShowRegularGridWhenEmpty="False"
                      EmptyDataText="No Sessions to Display."
                      OnRowDataBound="lvDataBound"
                     OnRowCommand="lvCommand"
                     Visible="true">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <div class="container" id="mainContent">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </LayoutTemplate>

                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <div class="row instructorItem">
                                <div class="col-2 sessionStartTimeDiv">
                                   <p class="sessionStartTime"><%#Eval("SessionStartTime")%></p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-2 instructorHeadshotDiv">
                                    <asp:Image class="instructorHeadshot" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("InstructorHeadshot")%>' />
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-5 sessionInfoDiv">
                                    <h3 class="instructorName"><%#Eval("InstructorName")%></h3>
                                    <p class="sessionInfo"><%#Eval("SessionInfo")%></p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-3 checkInBtnDiv">
                                   <asp:Button class="checkInBtn" ID="checkInBtn" runat="server" OnClick="CheckInBtn_Click" Text="Check-In"></asp:Button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <hr />
                           </ItemTemplate>

                           <EmptyDataTemplate>
                              <br />
                               <br />
                                No Sessions to Display
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>

   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ASPX.CS: (How I populate Listview)

```
private void UpdateInstructorListView()
    {
        //Make Data table to hold ListViewItem Data 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("SessionStartTime");
        dt.Columns.Add("InstructorHeadshot");
        dt.Columns.Add("InstructorName");
        dt.Columns.Add("SessionInfo");
        DataRow dr;

        foreach (Session S in UpcomingSessions)
        {
            foreach (Enrollment I in S.Instructors())
            {
                //
                SessionId = S.SessionId;
                SessionStartTime = S.FirstDateTime().ToShortTimeString();
                InstructorHeadshot = I.Headshot;
                InstructorName = I.FirstName + " " + I.LastName;
                SessionInfo = S.Name + " , " + S.Room.ToString();


                //Fill rows in DataTable with variables
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["SessionStartTime"] = SessionStartTime;
                dr["InstructorHeadshot"] = InstructorHeadshot;
                dr["InstructorName"] = InstructorName;
                dr["SessionInfo"] = SessionInfo;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }


        //Bind datatable to lv
        lvInstructors.DataSource = dt;
        lvInstructors.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use FindControl multiple times. First, find the ListView in the correct Repeater Item.

```
var listview = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("ListView1") as ListView;
```

Then locate the Button in the correct ListView item.

```
var button = listview.Items[j].FindControl("checkInBtn") as Button;
```

Now you have access to the Button.

```
button.Text = "Button found!";
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Button ID="checkInBtn" runat="server" Text="Button" />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Hey, @VDWWD, thanks for the response. I've edited my question to include some code, but I mis-spoke in my question - I used, Repeated when I should've said UpdatePanel (thought they could be used interchangeably) - should the solution still be the same? I notice there is no Items property to access on UpdateList.

What Im trying to do is have checkInBtn "flash" the time in SessionStartTime is 5 minutes in the past of DateTime.now

Comment: Thank You again, by the way